# Issue in React by using Redux, actions and dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

I have a login form which needs to re-direct a user to a landing page if the user's email exists in the database.

I have a class called "FormToLogin" with a method called `login`. In the `login` method, I dispatch data and `this.props.history` to an action called `loginAct`.

Container:

```
class FormToLogin extends Component {
    login = fullForm => {

        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        const data = {[user]: {...fullForm}}

        return dispatch(login(data, this.props.history)) <-- apparently, passing history to an action is not good)

    }
}
```

As you can see, I call the action by passing Data (which will include the email address entered by the user) and the history because I want to make a `.push('/new_url')` if the email exists in the database.

Action:

```
export const login = (data, history, dispatch) => {
    return api.post(url, data)

       .then(({ status, h, data }) => {
         // whatever if it returns 200
       }

       .catch(({ response }) => {
           dispatch(loginFail());

           const status = (response || {}).status;

           if (status === 401 && hasError(error_user, response.data)) {

               history.push('/new_url') // This is INCORRECT
               ?? -- what do I need here -- ??
           }
       })
}
```

I have been told that it's bad practice to pass Route history to an Action. 
So, `history.push()` shouldn't happen here.
I've been suggested to add a catch to a container level ("FormToLogin").

So, I've tried to create a catch in the `Container(FormToLogin)` when I call the Action with `dispatch(login(data))`, but it doesn't work. Also, `var status` doesn't exist in the container.

```
BEFORE: return dispatch(login(data, this.props.history))
AFTER: .catch(e => { 
           if (status === 401 && hasError(
               error_user, 
               e.response.data
              )) { 
               history.push('/new_url); 
              } throw e; })
```

**What do I need to add or change?**

Comment: You need to chain you action with another one that will redirect: chat library is to connect you react-router to redux: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this issue.

1) Accessing history object inside Action creator without explicitly passing.

// create history object

`history.js`

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'

export default createHistory()
```

`action.js`

```
import history from './history'

history.push('/new_url') // use it wherever you want.
```

2) If you don't want it inside action then handle that inside formLogin.

When dispatching `dispatch(loginFail());`, inside loginFail function set state of email_address. You could get that state using connect function inside FormToLogin due to react-redux library using props.

Inside render function you could write.

```
if (this.props.isEmailAddress) { history.push('/new_url') }
```